# Oracle SQL - Calculating Performance Indicators

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm wondering if someone could help/enlighten me - apologies for the long one.

I have a table like the following example:

```
ID  | PersonID  | Year  | Status    | Status_A
----------------------------------------
1   |   1       | 2015  |   C       |   SP1
2   |   2       | 2015  |   B       |   SP1
3   |   3       | 2016  |   C       |   SP2
```

I need to do some analysis on this table so I can get (e.g.):

> - Total Number of People
> - Percentage of the total number of people who have Status C for multiple years
> - Percentage of the total number of people who have Status C for one year
> - Percentage of the total number of people who have Status_A SP1 for multiple years
> - Percentage of the total number of people who have Status2 SP1 for one year
> - Percentage of the total number of people who have Status2 SP1 and Status C for multiple years
> - Percentage of the total number of people who have Status2 SP1 and Status C and Status B for multiple years
> - etc.

So far I am using sub queries then doing all my calculations in the select.   Each item is a performance indicator and must have an 'X' beside it if it exceeds a target:

(e.g)

### (needs to concat the HTML)

```
SELECT
  '<tr>
<th>Performance Indicator 1</th>
<td>Performance Indicator Text</td>
<td>Year 2015: '
  || (STATUS1+STATUS2)
  || ' ('
  || NVL(ROUND(100*((STATUS1+STATUS2)/NULLIF(TOTAL2,0)),2),0)
  || '%)'
  ||
  CASE
    WHEN ROUND(100*((STATUS1+STATUS2)/NULLIF(TOTAL2,0)),2)>= 15
    THEN ' X'
  END
  || '</td><td> Year 2016: '
  || (STATUS1+STATUS2)
  || ' ('
  || NVL(ROUND(100*((STATUS1+STATUS2)/NULLIF(TOTAL3,0)),2),0)
  || '%) '
  ||
  CASE
    WHEN ROUND(100*((STATUS1+STATUS2)/NULLIF(TOTAL3,0)),2)>= 15
    THEN ' X'
  END
  || '</td>
<td></td>
</tr>'
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      COUNT(*) AS TOTAL2
    FROM
      TABLE
    WHERE
      YEAR = '2015'
  )
  ,
  (
    SELECT
      COUNT(*) AS TOTAL3
    FROM
      TABLE
    WHERE
      YEAR = '2016'
  )
  ,
  (
    SELECT
      COUNT(*) AS STATUS1
    FROM
      TABLE
    WHERE
      Status = 'C'
  )
  ,
  (
    SELECT
      COUNT(*) AS STATUS2
    FROM
      TABLE
    WHERE
      Status = 'B'
  )
  etc.
```

This is going to get extremely inefficient and wieldy when done across all the required performance indicators.   I'm sure there is a much better/simpler method out there.   Can anyone please help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to use the following trick which uses `with` statement:

```
select 
  NVL(ROUND(100*((STATUS1+STATUS2)/NULLIF(TOTAL2,0)),2),0) as kpi1,
  ... ,
  ... ,
  ... ,
from (
    with data as (
      select * from table
      where year between 2015 and 2016
         or status in ('B','C')
    )
    select
      count(case when year=2015 then 1 else NULL end) as total2,
      count(case when year=2016 then 1 else NULL end) as total3,
      count(case when status='C' then 1 else NULL end) as status1,
      count(case when status='B' then 1 else NULL end) as status2
    from data
);
```

Beside that you may want to check sqlplus's feature `SET MARKUP HTML ON` (if you are using sqlplus for your report)